# How to create a dataframe taking only the common variables from two dataframe

Tags: r

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))

employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)


employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
age <- c(43, 45, 36)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
employ.data2 <- data.frame(employee, age, startdate)
```

I need a dataframe of employee,startdate i.e only same variable from the two dataframe

Comment: Try: `employ.data[,intersect(colnames(employ.data), colnames(employ.data2))]`

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly known as "joining" two "tables" (or data.frames in R), and is a common operation in databases. For simplicity in R, you could use the `merge` function:

```
merge(employ.data, employ.data2, by='employee') # to compare only by employee
merge(employ.data, employ.data2) # let merge use all columns in common
```

But wait, there's more! `merge` allows you to specify

- which column in the two data.frames to use for the comparison (see arguments `by.x` and `by.y`)
- if you want *all* rows from the first data.frame and/or *all* rows from the second data.frame (arguments `all`, `all.x` and `all.y`) - this is commonly referred as "inner join" (`all=FALSE`), or full, left or right join.

If you want a tid more advanced, you could look into the pacakge `dplyr` which employs the verbs `inner_join` and `left_join` as functions (and more!) which improves readability of your code.